# allow one digit or two digit for time to add in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, time

This is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pathik2012/0tg2awdm/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input name="time" placeholder="hh:mm"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("time24", function(value, element) {
    if (!/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(value)) return false;
    var parts = value.split(':');
    if (parts[0] > 23 || parts[1] > 59) return false;
    return true;
}, "Invalid time format.");

$(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            time: {
               required: true,
               time24: true
             }
        }
    });
});
```

I want to allow add `hh` as one digit or two digits like `9:00` and `09:00` both should be work. I tried to make changes in `if (!/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(value)) return false;` but it doesn't work. Can any one please help?

Comment: ^\d{1,2}:\d{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have the first `d{2}` in your regular expression, you can instead use `d{1,2}`

Comment: @PathikVejani mark his answer as true if it worked for you

Comment: @symlink yes, I was waiting to finished of `7 minutes`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{n,m}` quantifier, `\d{1,2}` which means match digit one or two time

or you can extend your regex even further

```
(?:0?\d|1\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d|60)
```

[image]

```js
let test = (str)=>{
  return /^(?:0?\d|1\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d|60)$/.test(str)
}

console.log(test('09:00'))
console.log(test('9:00'))
console.log(test('90:00'))
console.log(test('23:00'))
console.log(test('23:59'))
```

Comment: ohh.. great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Your problem is with these parts in your reg exp:

`d{2}`

This means, "a digit must occur exactly twice." Since you want the digit to occur "from one to two times," you need to change those sections to this:

`d{1,2}`

I also updated the placeholder text in the input box from "hh:mm:ss" to "hh:mm" to match the reg exp.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("time24", function(value, element) {
    if (!/^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$/.test(value)) return false;
    var parts = value.split(':');
    /* if (parts[0] > 23 || parts[1] > 59 || parts[2] > 59) return false; */
    if (parts[0] > 23 || parts[1] > 59) return false;
    return true;
}, "Invalid time format.");

$(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            time: {
               required: true,
               time24: true
             }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input name="time" placeholder="hh:mm"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!